# How to detect CRON issues from the server side?

Tags: magento2, cron, server-setup

It seems like we're having CRON issues, I usually check it via this command below.

```
./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:history
```

[image: Magento 2 CRON issues]

How could I check it more precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to check it via DB and logs, you will be able the check it via MySQL using this command too:

```
select * from cron_schedule where status='error';
```

For example:

```
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| schedule_id | job_code                                            | status | messages                                  | created_at          | scheduled_at        | executed_at         | finished_at |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|     8504994 | sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert            | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 00:49:05 | 2021-07-21 01:48:00 | 2021-07-21 01:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8505054 | sales_send_order_emails                             | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 00:49:05 | 2021-07-21 01:48:00 | 2021-07-21 01:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8505114 | sales_send_order_invoice_emails                     | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 00:49:05 | 2021-07-21 01:48:00 | 2021-07-21 01:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8505234 | sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails                  | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 00:49:05 | 2021-07-21 01:48:00 | 2021-07-21 01:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8505303 | outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup            | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 00:49:05 | 2021-07-21 01:48:00 | 2021-07-21 01:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8505727 | staging_remove_updates                              | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 00:49:05 | 2021-07-21 01:48:00 | 2021-07-21 01:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8506565 | catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup       | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 01:49:04 | 2021-07-21 02:48:00 | 2021-07-21 02:49:01 | NULL        |
|     8506625 | catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush              | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 01:49:04 | 2021-07-21 02:48:00 | 2021-07-21 02:49:00 | NULL        |
|     8506818 | sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert              | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 01:49:04 | 2021-07-21 02:48:00 | 2021-07-21 02:49:00 | NULL        |
|     8507058 | sales_send_order_shipment_emails                    | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 01:49:05 | 2021-07-21 02:48:00 | 2021-07-21 02:49:00 | NULL        |
|     8507550 | staging_apply_version                               | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 01:49:05 | 2021-07-21 02:48:00 | 2021-07-21 02:49:00 | NULL        |
|     8507610 | staging_remove_updates                              | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 01:49:05 | 2021-07-21 02:48:00 | 2021-07-21 02:49:00 | NULL        |
|     8513013 | magemojo_cron_cleanup                               | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 04:49:05 | 2021-07-21 05:00:00 | 2021-07-21 05:02:09 | NULL        |
|     8513628 | mm_consumer_negotiableQuotePriceUpdate              | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 04:49:06 | 2021-07-21 05:02:00 | 2021-07-21 05:02:03 | NULL        |
|     8514014 | ddg_automation_campaign                             | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 04:49:06 | 2021-07-21 05:00:00 | 2021-07-21 05:02:09 | NULL        |
|     8524153 | magento_newrelicreporting_cron                      | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 10:49:01 | 2021-07-21 11:48:00 | 2021-07-21 11:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8524420 | indexer_update_all_views                            | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 10:49:01 | 2021-07-21 11:48:00 | 2021-07-21 11:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8525022 | mm_consumer_sharedCatalogUpdatePrice                | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 10:49:02 | 2021-07-21 11:48:00 | 2021-07-21 11:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8530245 | staging_synchronize_entities_period                 | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 13:49:02 | 2021-07-21 14:48:00 | 2021-07-21 14:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8530485 | mm_consumer_codegeneratorProcessor                  | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 13:49:02 | 2021-07-21 14:48:00 | 2021-07-21 14:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8530545 | mm_consumer_exportProcessor                         | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 13:49:02 | 2021-07-21 14:48:00 | 2021-07-21 14:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8530605 | mm_consumer_negotiableQuotePriceUpdate              | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 13:49:02 | 2021-07-21 14:48:00 | 2021-07-21 14:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8530845 | mm_consumer_inventoryQtyCounter                     | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 13:49:02 | 2021-07-21 14:48:00 | 2021-07-21 14:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8530905 | mm_consumer_async.operations.all                    | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 13:49:02 | 2021-07-21 14:48:00 | 2021-07-21 14:48:58 | NULL        |
|     8537950 | mm_consumer_product_action_attribute.website.update | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 17:49:05 | 2021-07-21 18:48:00 | 2021-07-21 18:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8538130 | mm_consumer_negotiableQuotePriceUpdate              | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 17:49:05 | 2021-07-21 18:48:00 | 2021-07-21 18:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8538190 | mm_consumer_sharedCatalogUpdatePrice                | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 17:49:05 | 2021-07-21 18:48:00 | 2021-07-21 18:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8538250 | mm_consumer_sharedCatalogUpdateCategoryPermissions  | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 17:49:05 | 2021-07-21 18:48:00 | 2021-07-21 18:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8538310 | mm_consumer_quoteItemCleaner                        | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 17:49:05 | 2021-07-21 18:48:00 | 2021-07-21 18:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8538370 | mm_consumer_inventoryQtyCounter                     | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 17:49:05 | 2021-07-21 18:48:00 | 2021-07-21 18:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8539250 | flush_preview_quotas                                | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 18:49:06 | 2021-07-21 19:48:00 | 2021-07-21 19:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8539591 | staging_remove_updates                              | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 18:49:06 | 2021-07-21 19:48:00 | 2021-07-21 19:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8539651 | staging_synchronize_entities_period                 | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 18:49:06 | 2021-07-21 19:48:00 | 2021-07-21 19:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8539771 | mm_consumer_product_action_attribute.update         | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 18:49:06 | 2021-07-21 19:48:00 | 2021-07-21 19:49:00 | NULL        |
|     8539891 | mm_consumer_codegeneratorProcessor                  | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 18:49:06 | 2021-07-21 19:48:00 | 2021-07-21 19:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8540311 | mm_consumer_async.operations.all                    | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 18:49:07 | 2021-07-21 19:48:00 | 2021-07-21 19:48:59 | NULL        |
|     8540921 | sales_send_order_shipment_emails                    | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 19:49:05 | 2021-07-21 20:48:00 | 2021-07-21 20:48:55 | NULL        |
|     8540981 | sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails                  | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 19:49:05 | 2021-07-21 20:48:00 | 2021-07-21 20:48:55 | NULL        |
|     8541412 | staging_apply_version                               | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 19:49:06 | 2021-07-21 20:48:00 | 2021-07-21 20:48:55 | NULL        |
|     8541472 | staging_remove_updates                              | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 19:49:06 | 2021-07-21 20:48:00 | 2021-07-21 20:48:55 | NULL        |
|     8541532 | staging_synchronize_entities_period                 | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 19:49:06 | 2021-07-21 20:48:00 | 2021-07-21 20:48:56 | NULL        |
|     8542012 | mm_consumer_sharedCatalogUpdateCategoryPermissions  | error  | Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally | 2021-07-21 19:49:06 | 2021-07-21 20:48:00 | 2021-07-21 20:48:50 | NULL        |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

The **'Parent Cron Process Terminated Abnormally'** usually has more information on it in the `/var/log/cron.log`.

For example:

```
[2021-05-21 03:48:53] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.0654166666667
[2021-05-21 03:49:09] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.1895833333333
[2021-05-21 03:49:14] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.1908333333333
[2021-05-21 03:49:19] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.11875
[2021-05-21 03:49:24] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.0158333333333
[2021-05-21 03:49:35] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.0445833333333
[2021-05-21 03:49:40] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.02125
[2021-05-21 03:49:52] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.0275
[2021-05-21 04:03:03] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.04875
[2021-05-21 04:03:08] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.0916666666667
[2021-05-21 04:03:13] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.0508333333333
[2021-05-21 04:03:18] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.1391666666667
[2021-05-21 04:03:24] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.0545833333333
[2021-05-21 04:03:29] WARN Crons suspended due to high load average: 2.06375
```

This indicates the cron is hitting the max load.

### After solving the issues

After solve the issues you might be able to reset the CRON schedule running these two commands too:

```
rm /srv/public_html/var/cron/* -rf
```

**DB**

```
truncate cron_schedule;
```